# vim automatically highlights 'test' whenever vimrc is sourced

Tags: vim

Whenever I reload vim after editing my `.vimrc` (`:so $MYVIMRC`) the word `test` is always highlighted. I did a search in my `.vimrc` and the word '`test`' isn't even in there.

Why is this happening? I'm on windows BTW and my plugins are `pathogen`, `supertab`, `zencoding`, `nerdtree`, and `surround`.

Comment: Sharing your `.vimrc` and other configs would help us to help You. Try uploading them to e.g. https://gist.github.com .

Comment: It's may be happening because there is a `test` search in some plugin.

Comment: Try running vim without your vimrc to see if this still happens. (e.g. `vim -u NONE`)

Comment: You could try `:set nohls` to see if it a search term that is being highlighted. Otherwise it might be syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have `test` in your search register (`@/`), which is stored in `.viminfo` between sessions by default, and `set hlsearch` in your `.vimrc`. You can check content of the search register with the command

```
echo @/
```

Once I had same issue, but I can't reproduce it now on Linux, so maybe it was fixed or Windows specific. Though I still have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
if @/ == ''
    set hlsearch
endif
```

I can leave `'hlsearch'` disabled, since I have a mapping to toggle it (now I wonder if I need this lines at all...). This may not be your case, so another variants are to disable search highlighting

```
set hlsearch
nohlsearch
```

or just empty search register

```
set hlsearch
let @/=''
```

Comment: Before all that, why don't you check what's in the search register for starters